# First array value not being accessed in Arduino sketch

Tags: arrays, arduino

I'm creating a code that recreate's a clock without using a RTC module. I was busy adding in the days. The problem came when looping through the array. when the `index==0`, it gives a random form of char.
This is the code that doesn't work:

```
int theDayindex=0;
String weekDay[]={"maandag","dinsdag","woensdag","donderdag","vrijdag","zaterdag","zondag"};
String theDaydisplay=weekDay[theDayindex];
    theDayindex++;
    theDaydisplay=weekDay[theDayindex];
    if(theDayindex>=6){
      theDayindex=0;
    }
```

I think the problem is that when you loop through the code, it does not detect 0 as an index. I'm not really familiar with the C language so it might work differently.

```c
#include <Wire.h>
#include <hd44780.h>
#include <hd44780ioClass/hd44780_I2Cexp.h>
#include <dht.h>
#include <NewPing.h>

int page = 1;
int secs = 0;
int mins = 52;
int hors = 20;
int T;
int H;
int IRpin = 13;
int Timer = 0;
int theDayindex = 0;
String weekDay[] = {
  "maandag",
  "dinsdag",
  "woensdag",
  "donderdag",
  "vrijdag",
  "zaterdag",
  "zondag"
};
String theDaydisplay = weekDay[theDayindex];

hd44780_I2Cexp lcd;
dht DHT;
NewPing sonar(11, 12, 400);

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  lcd.begin(16, 2);
  lcd.init();
  lcd.backlight();
}

void loop() {
  secs++;
  Timer++;
  theDayindex++;
  theDaydisplay = weekDay[theDayindex];
  if (theDayindex >= 6) {
    theDayindex = 0;
  }
  Serial.println(theDayindex);
  Serial.println(theDaydisplay);
  unsigned int dstnc = sonar.ping_cm();
  if (dstnc <= 30) {
    lcd.backlight();
    lcd.display();
    Timer = 0;
    page++;
  }
  if (secs >= 60) {
    secs = 0;
    mins++;
    lcd.clear();
  }
  if (mins >= 60) {
    hors++;
    mins = 0;
    secs = 0;
    lcd.clear();
  }
  if (hors >= 24) {
    hors = 0;
    mins = 0;
    secs = 0;
    lcd.clear();
    theDayindex++;
    theDaydisplay = weekDay[theDayindex];
    if (theDayindex >= 6) {
      theDayindex = 0;
    }
  }
  if (Timer >= 60) {
    page = 1;
    lcd.noBacklight();
    lcd.noDisplay();
  }
  if (page == 1) {
    lcd.clear();
    lcd.setCursor(0, 2);
    lcd.print(theDaydisplay);
    lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
    lcd.print(hors);
    lcd.setCursor(2, 0);
    lcd.print(":");
    lcd.setCursor(3, 0);
    lcd.print(mins);
    lcd.setCursor(5, 0);
    lcd.print(":");
    lcd.setCursor(6, 0);
    lcd.print(secs);
  }
  if (page == 2) {
    int chk = DHT.read11(7);
    H = DHT.humidity;
    T = DHT.temperature;
    lcd.clear();
    lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
    lcd.print("Hum:");
    lcd.setCursor(4, 0);
    lcd.print(H);
    lcd.setCursor(9, 0);
    lcd.print("temp: ");
    lcd.setCursor(14, 0);
    lcd.print(T);
  }
  if (page >= 3) {
    page = 1;
  }
  delay(955);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the issue is the loop not accessing the first index, then the culprit is:

```
theDayindex++;
```

The `theDayindex` is first set to 0 but immediately incremented when the loop starts. So just move the index increments to the end of your loop.

```c
#include <Wire.h>

#include <hd44780.h>

#include <hd44780ioClass/hd44780_I2Cexp.h>

#include <dht.h>

#include <NewPing.h>

int page = 1;
int secs = 0;
int mins = 52;
int hors = 20;
int T;
int H;
int IRpin = 13;
int Timer = 0;
int theDayindex = 0;
String weekDay[] = {
  "maandag",
  "dinsdag",
  "woensdag",
  "donderdag",
  "vrijdag",
  "zaterdag",
  "zondag"
};
String theDaydisplay = weekDay[theDayindex];

hd44780_I2Cexp lcd;
dht DHT;
NewPing sonar(11, 12, 400);

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  lcd.begin(16, 2);
  lcd.init();
  lcd.backlight();
}

void loop() {
  theDaydisplay = weekDay[theDayindex];
  if (theDayindex >= 6) {
    theDayindex = 0;
  }
  Serial.println(theDayindex);
  Serial.println(theDaydisplay);
  unsigned int dstnc = sonar.ping_cm();
  if (dstnc <= 30) {
    lcd.backlight();
    lcd.display();
    Timer = 0;
    page++;
  }
  if (secs >= 60) {
    secs = 0;
    mins++;
    lcd.clear();
  }
  if (mins >= 60) {
    hors++;
    mins = 0;
    secs = 0;
    lcd.clear();
  }
  if (hors >= 24) {
    hors = 0;
    mins = 0;
    secs = 0;
    lcd.clear();
    theDayindex++;
    theDaydisplay = weekDay[theDayindex];
    if (theDayindex >= 6) {
      theDayindex = 0;
    }
  }
  if (Timer >= 60) {
    page = 1;
    lcd.noBacklight();
    lcd.noDisplay();
  }
  if (page == 1) {
    lcd.clear();
    lcd.setCursor(0, 2);
    lcd.print(theDaydisplay);
    lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
    lcd.print(hors);
    lcd.setCursor(2, 0);
    lcd.print(":");
    lcd.setCursor(3, 0);
    lcd.print(mins);
    lcd.setCursor(5, 0);
    lcd.print(":");
    lcd.setCursor(6, 0);
    lcd.print(secs);
  }
  if (page == 2) {
    int chk = DHT.read11(7);
    H = DHT.humidity;
    T = DHT.temperature;
    lcd.clear();
    lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
    lcd.print("Hum:");
    lcd.setCursor(4, 0);
    lcd.print(H);
    lcd.setCursor(9, 0);
    lcd.print("temp: ");
    lcd.setCursor(14, 0);
    lcd.print(T);
  }
  if (page >= 3) {
    page = 1;
  }
  delay(955);

  secs++;
  Timer++;
  theDayindex++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As Stormix answared, you never use `weekDay[0]`. When `theDaydisplay=weekDay[theDayindex]` is executed for the first time, `theDayIndex` has already been incremented, so you are accessing `weekDay[1]`. Just changing the lines order should solve your problem.

```
int theDayindex=0;
String weekDay[]={"maandag","dinsdag","woensdag","donderdag","vrijdag","zaterdag","zondag"};
String theDaydisplay=weekDay[theDayindex];
    theDaydisplay=weekDay[theDayindex];
    theDayindex++;
    if(theDayindex>=6){
      theDayindex=0;
    }
```